# MapFragment issue in onSelectFragment view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I've created a fragment, *Fragment01*, that extends `MapFragment`. Problem is that because it doesn't extend `Fragment` anymore, now the `onSelectFragment` part of my *MainActivity* doesn't work anymore. What do I need to change in my *MainActivity* to get it to work like before? The error I'm getting is on the line   `newFragment = new Fragment01();` where it says ***Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment01 to Fragment***. Being a noob, I simply tried with `newMapFragment = new Fragment01();` but that didn't do it.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    StartFragment startfragment = new StartFragment();

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, startfragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void onSelectFragment(View view){

    Fragment newFragment;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnstartfragment)) {
        newFragment = new StartFragment();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnfragment01)) {
        newFragment = new Fragment01();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnfragment02)) {
        newFragment = new Fragment02();
    } else {
        newFragment = new StartFragment();
    }
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be error with different `Fragment` hierarchies: from support library and platform.
Check your imports and hierarchy of `MapFragment`.

These are two **different** types:

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

`android.app.Fragment`

Comment: The imports in *MainActivity* are from the support library *(android.support.v4.app.*)* that activity doesn't share any imports with the fragment (*Fragment01*). Could you please explain what you mean with check the hierarchy of MapFragment? It's simply *Fragment01* extending *MapFragment* and then some example code I copied from a website.

Comment: what is the full class name of ``MapFragment`` ?? if ``MapFragment`` extends ``android.app.Fragment`` it won't be assigned to ``android.support.v4.app.Fragment``